# Get the last part of a string in a list

Tags: python

I have a list which contains the following `string` element.

```py
myList = ['120$My life cycle 3$121$My daily routine 2']
```

I perform a `.split("$")` operation and get the following new list.

```py
templist = str(myList).split("$")
```

I want to be able to store all the integer values from this `templist` which are at even indexes after the split.I want to return a list of integers.

```
Expected output: [120, 121]
```

Comment: So, you just want all numbers within a string? Why are you splitting on `$`?

Comment: @LauraSmith, how are you applying the split, are you using `myList[0].split("$")`?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf See my edits. I use str() then splits

Comment: There is no 120 at 0-index -its delimited by & not $

Comment: still you have `&` between `120` and  `My life cycle`. `.split('$')` will not do and  converting list to `str` will leave the brackets and quote char

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split at $ and use a list comprehension [with `str.isdigit()` to](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) extract numbers:

```
mylist = ['120$My life cycle$121$My daily routine','some$222$othr$text$42']

# split each thing in mylist at $, for each split-result, keep only those that
# contain only numbers and convert them to integer
splitted = [[int(i) for i in p.split("$") if i.isdigit()] for p in mylist] 

print(splitted) # [[120, 121], [222, 42]]
```

This will produce a list of lists and convert the "string" numbers into integers. it only works for positive numbers-strings without sign - with sign you can exchange `isdigit()` for another function:

```
def isInt(t):
    try:
        _ = int(t)
        return True
    except:
        return False

mylist = ['-120$My life cycle$121$My daily routine','some$222$othr$text$42']
splitted = [[int(i) for i in p.split("$") if isInt(i) ] for p in mylist] 

print(splitted) # [[-120, 121], [222, 42]]
```

---

To get a flattened list no matter how many strings are in `myList`:

```
intlist = list(map(int,( d for d in '$'.join(myList).split("$") if isInt(d))))
print(intlist) # [-120, 121, 222, 42]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Updated version:**

```
import re
myList = ['120$My life cycle 3$121$My daily routine 2']
myList = myList[0].split('$')
numbers = []
for i in range(0,len(myList),2):
        temp = re.findall(r'\d+', myList[i])[0]
        numbers.append(temp)
'''
.finall() returns list of all occurences of a pattern in a given string.
The pattern says map all digits in the string. If they are next to each
other count them as one element in final list. We use index 0 of the 
myList as thats the string we want to work with.
'''
results = list(map(int, numbers)) # this line performs an int() operation on each of the elements of numbers.
print(results)
```

Why not just use `re`?

`re` is a library for regular expresions in python. They help you find patterns.

```
import re
myList = ['120$My life cycle 3$121$My daily routine 2']
numbers = re.findall(r'\d+$', myList[0]) 
'''
.finall() returns list of all occurences of a pattern in a given string.
The pattern says map all digits in the string. If they are next to each
other count them as one element in final list. We use index 0 of the 
myList as thats the string we want to work with.
'''
results = list(map(int, numbers)) # this line performs an int() operation on each of the elements of numbers. 
print(results)
```

Comment: for example, if I use something like this. ```['120&My life cycle 3$121$My daily routine 2']```, I only want the results to have ```[120, 121]```, but that is not the case here. May you please edit to reflect this?

Comment: @LauraSmith Will it consistently be a 3 digit number you want to extract and the number after routine will not be a 3 digit number?

Comment: It is always a number followed by $ followed by a string which could contain numbers followed by $ and this pattern continues. I am only interested in the number which is not part of the strings. The number could be 4 digits or any number of digits. Please refer to the ```myList = ['120$My life cycle 3$121$My daily routine 2']```

Comment: `r'\d+$` will look for numbers only at the end of each line. `'$'` is a special regex character with special meaning -you need to escape it. use `'r'\d+(?:\$|$)'` instead.

Comment: @Matej Novosad has a better answer for the changed use case

Comment: @PatrickArtner Yes OP changed the question 3 times during this answers stay so I decided to write a new one because this one was no longer the best solution from my POV.

Comment: @MatejNovosad I thought I was losing it for a bit there as I swore that I had copied the test case properly.

Comment: @MatthewGaiser your answer was fully correct and your testcase was the same as with OP. She just edited it like 3 times. :D

Answer (score 1):

First off we split string with `'$'` as separator. And then we just iterate through every other result from the new list, convert it into integer and append it to results.

```
myList = ['120$My life cycle 3$121$My daily routine 2']
myList = myList[0].split('$')
results = []
for i in range(0,len(myList),2):
    results.append(int(myList[i]))
print(results)
# [120, 121]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this?

```
a = ['100$My String 1A$290$My String 1B']
>>> for x in a:
...   [int(s) for s in x.split("$") if s.isdigit()]
...
[100, 290]
```

Comment: Did you try it on the sample input and did you get the output? It doesnt seem to work :(

Comment: in your string there is '&' instead of '$' so I am only getting [121] as output. Is it something wrong with your **string** in the question?

Comment: That was a typo. Updated to reflect the fix

Comment: I just took your string out of array and then ran this `[int(s) for s in mystr.split("$") if s.isdigit()]` and it worked

Comment: For example, if my input is ```['100$My String 1A$290$My String 1B']```, I only get 290 with you solution? Can you verify this?

Comment: if you do str(myList) you will get the resultant array as following: `["['100", 'My String 1A', '290', "My String 1B']"]` So, the first element has `["['100"` which is not a digit hence you're not seeing the first element. In order to avoid it, you need to loop into each string element in the list and do like what I said.